# How to work without closures in Emacs lisp dynamic scoping

Tags: closures, elisp, dynamic-scope

I know Emacs 24 introduced lexical scoping; that is great but I work with lexical scoping all the time, and I'm trying to see from a different point of view with dynamic scoping.

Originally I just did what I would always do, rely on a closure:

```
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 
  (lambda () 
    (dolist (p '(("M-l" . cider-load-current-buffer)
         ("M-e" . cider-eval-last-expression)))
      (local-set-key 
       (kbd (car p)) 
       (lambda () (interactive) (save-buffer) (cdr p))))))
```

After finally understanding why p is undefined when the lambda runs, I came up with this to force the evaluation of p in the context of the dolist rather than when the lambda runs.

```
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 
  (lambda () 
    (dolist (p '(("M-l" . cider-load-current-buffer)
         ("M-e" . cider-eval-last-expression)))
      (local-set-key 
       (kbd (car p)) 
       (cons 'lambda `(() (interactive) (save-buffer) (funcall (quote ,(cdr p)))))))))
```

Is this the classical solution for solving the problem without closures and lexical scoping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this like this if I wanted to keep bindings in a list like you.
I actually prefer to spell out `local-set-key` for each command.

```
(defun save-before-call (f)
  `(lambda()
     (interactive)
     (save-buffer)
     (funcall #',f)))

(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (mapc (lambda(x)(local-set-key
                     (kbd (car x))
                     (save-before-call (cdr x))))
          '(("M-l" . cider-load-current-buffer)
            ("M-e" . cider-eval-last-expression)))))
```